# Android : widget launching screen : draw a loading icon (e.g circle bar) like Fancy Widget

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, android-appwidget

I'm looking for a way to draw a loading icon (e.g circle bar) while my widget is launching.
By default, I use the initial layout described in appwidget-provider xml resource file  :
( android:initialLayout xml element )

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minWidth="294dp"
android:minHeight="144dp"
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_message"
android:configure="fr.cdcorp.homewidget.configurationActivity.WDWidgetConfiguration"
android:updatePeriodMillis="43200000" 
/>
```

So, in this initial layout (widget_message.xml), I use an ImageView in which src is an animated GIF circle bar.
But, this doesn't work, I just see the 1st frame of the gif, not animated Gif.
AFAIK this can be done, Fancy Widget does it.
Any Help would be appreciate !!
Thanks, 
C.D

Answer (score 0):

try this, it worked for me..
i use an activity launched from on click of appWidge, but it should work for your configuration activity too)

```
    final class GIFView extends View {

        Movie movie, movie1;
        InputStream is = null, is1 = null;
        long moviestart;


        public GIFView(Context context) {
            super(context);

            is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.youranimatedgif);
            movie = Movie.decodeStream(is);


        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            super.onDraw(canvas);

            try{
            long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

            if (moviestart == 0) { // first time
                moviestart = now;

            }

            int relTime = (int) ((now - moviestart) % movie.duration());
            System.out.println("time=" + relTime + "\treltime=" + movie.duration());
            movie.setTime(relTime);

                //this will draw on the top left corner of your display
                movie.draw(canvas, 0,0);



            this.invalidate();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                     //make you stuff here
            }
        }
    }




public class YuorActivity extends Activity {    

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try{        

        setContentView(new GIFView(this));
        new InitTask().execute(this);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
                //do your stuff here
        }

    }

}
```

hope this help...